# How to run multiple instances of Ethereum Wallet simultaneously on a Windows machine?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

When I do Ethereum development, I'd like the run multiple instances of Ethereum Wallet at the same time on my work machine. For example, I have a ganache development node server, a private-net server with three geth nodes, and a full node mainnet server, currently I created three different Ethereum Wallet appdata folders, and sym-link the "%APPDATA%\Ethereum Wallet" system folder to one of the three different folders when launching Ethereum Wallet with a different script each time. However, that's not possible when I want to launch those three Ethereum Wallet instances at the same time as they all look for the same "%APPDATA%\Ethereum Wallet" system folder. For geth I know I can use --datadir option to specify an appdata folder different from the "%APPDATA%\Ethereum" system default, and then run multiple instances of geth simultaneously on one machine. Is there a similar option for the "Ethereum Wallet" application? Thanks.

EDIT: By "Ethereum Wallet", I mean the Mist-based official Ethereum Wallet application, downloadable from the the official ethereum.org website. https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases

Comment: I don't know what "Ethereum Wallet" is. Can you share a link? Also how do you start it?

Comment: @cleanunicorn see the edited part above.

Comment: the only thing to run multiple instances of `geth` is to use another -datadir and another port number. Mist uses `geth` as a backend

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the multiple wallets? can you give us some more context? If you are not simulating miners then I do not see the advantage of having multiple wallets running over having one wallet controlling multiple addresses?

Comment: @Nulik I know how to run multiple geth as I have stated in the question already, however here I need to run multiple instances of Ethereum Wallet (Mist) for development purposes here, as they need to connect to different node servers via the --rpc argument.

Comment: @davinci26 It's for development purposes, like I said, I have multiple node servers running, one is running ganache, one is running a geth private net, and finally one is running a mainnet full node, I need to connect to all of them from my own work machine to cross-check the performance of the developed smart contracts. Currently I use scripts with rmdir and mklink to make the APPDATA folder symlinking to different data directories, however only one instance of Ethereum Wallet can be running at the same time, and it'd be a great productivity boost if I can run them simultaneously.

Comment: @hellopeach, each instance of Mist runs it's own instance of `geth` , so there you go, modify the port number and datadir and that's it

Comment: @Nulik the problem is that at least on windows the Ethereum Wallet/Mist application use the same appdata directory, which is "%APPDATA%\Ethereum Wallet", and under that appdata directory it stores information like Watched Tokens, Deployed Contracts, etc. etc. so if I run multiple instances of Ethereum Wallet at the same time, those data will get messed up.